# Read simple XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to read a very simple xml file using linq. I know how to do it using for loops over child nodes but I am trying to learn linq. Anyways, I have a file:

```
<firstElement>
  <Setting Name="appDataPath" Value="some\\path" />
  <Setting Name="appConfigFileName" Value="somename.xml" />
  <Setting Name="appConfigFilePath"  Value="some\\path" />
</firstElement>
```

and I want to get the setting attributes. I have this code:

```
//Load xml
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fullyQualifiedPath);

var settings = from item in xdoc.Descendants("firstElement")
     select new
     {
         name = item.Attribute("Name").Value,
         val = item.Attribute("Value").Value
     };

     // create a dictionary
     Dictionary<string, string> settingsDictionary = 
                        new Dictionary<string, string>();

   //Loop through results
   foreach (var setting in settings)
   {
      settingsDictionary.Add(setting.name, setting.val);
   }

   xdoc.Save(fullyQualifiedPath);
```

For some reason settings is null after the query. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is `eStack`?

Comment: Does `xdoc.Save(fullyQualifiedPath);` have anything to do with your problem? Is it empty in the xml document on disk after save and that is the issue? If not then remove this line, it only adds confusion to the question. Also you have a part `Descendants("eStack")`, but I see no `eStack` node in the fragment.

Comment: try this: 
`from item in xdoc.Descendants("Setting")`

Comment: sorry; eStack is firstElement and no, the fullyQualifiedPath is not null. document is loading properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to obtain only the Setting nodes write:

`from item in xdoc.Descendants("Setting")`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any elements named `eStack`.  Try this instead...

```
var settingsDictionary = xdoc.Descendants("Setting")
                             .ToDictionary(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name"), 
                                           x => (string)x.Attribute("Value")
                                           );
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, this also works. eStack is the name of the first element. I just made an error when changing from my actual code to place holders to ask the question.

Comment: is that case you would want to call `.Descendants()` after selecting the `eStack` element